# how to write two elements into one row in Python

Tags: python

The objective is very simple, suppose I have a data array `x`, and a label array `y`, they are two separated files. For example:

```
x= [['first sentence'],['second sentence'],['third sentence']]
y= [1,0,1]
```

I want to get a combined 3*2 csv file as:

```
first sentence, 1
second sentence, 0
third sentence, 1
```

Is there any easy way to do the job? My code is to import `csv` package and use a double loop, but I am sure there exist a simpler way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `zip`

```
x= [['first sentence'],['second sentence'],['third sentence']]
y= [1,0,1]

for zx,zy in zip(x, y):
    print('{}, {}'.format(zx[0], zy))
```

output:

```
first sentence, 1
second sentence, 0
third sentence, 1
```

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot, and I found that you have answered several questions raised by me, especially you explained to me in detail how `zip` ,`map`functions. Thanks again. I posted another question related to this one, may you have a look? ^_^

Answer (score 5):

Use `zip()`.

```
x = [['first sentence'],['second sentence'],['third sentence']]
y = [1,0,1]
...
for a,b in zip(x,y):
    writer.writerow(a+[b])
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
x = [['first sentence'],['second sentence'],['third sentence']]
y = [1,0,1]
for i,j in zip(x, y):
    writer.writerow([i ,j])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
from csv import writer

x = [['first sentence'],['second sentence'],['third sentence']]
y = [1,0,1]

# only take first argument from the labels, zip them with the data and
# dump them into a file:
f = StringIO()  # you might want to use open(…)
writer(f).writerows(zip((z[0] for z in x), y))
f.seek(0)  # rewind the buffer
print f.read():
```

```
first sentence,1
second sentence,0
third sentence,1
```

C.f.

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#cStringIO.StringIO